# How do I take a number from a text file and replace it with that number +1?

Tags: python

I want to take a number, in my case 0, and add 1, then replace it back into the file. This is what I have so far:

```
def caseNumber():
    caseNumber = open('caseNumber.txt', "r")
    lastCase = caseNumber.read().splitlines()[0]
    Case = []
    Case.append(lastCase)
    newCase = [ int(x)+1 for x in Case ]

    with open('caseNumber.txt', mode = 'a',
    encoding = 'utf-8') as my_file:
        my_file.write('{}'.format(newCase))

    print('Thankyou, your case number is {}, Write it down!'.format(newCase))
```

After this is run, i get:

this is what is added to the file:  0000[1]    (the number in the file was 0000
 to start off with, but it added [1] aswell)

Basically, the part I am stuck on is adding 1 to the number without the brackets.

Comment: Incidentally, your `Case` is identical to `lastCase` , and there is no point in creating it.

Comment: What is the format of the file? Is there other stuff in the file or just this number? It started as 0000, do you want to keep leading zeros? Will this number get large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a list comprehension since you only need 1 item.

Since you're converting list to string you get the list representation: with brackets.

Note that it's not the only problem: you're appending to your text file (`a` mode), you don't replace the number. You have to write the file from scratch. But for that, you have to save full file contents when reading the first time. My proposal:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    number,_,rest = f.read().partition(" ") # split left value only
    number = str(int(number)+1)   # increment and convert back to string

with open('file.txt',"w") as f:
    f.write(" ".join([number,rest])) # write back file fully
```

So if the file contains:

```
0 this is a file
hello
```

each time you run this code above, the leading number is incremented, but the trailint text is kept

```
1 this is a file
hello
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3):

`newCase` is a list, which gets printed with its values enclosed in brackets.  If you just want the value *in* the list to get written to the file, you'll need to say that.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to take the value, and also replace the number within the text file with the new number.

Comment: What do you think the `[0]` in `lastCase = caseNumber.read().splitlines()[0]` is doing?

Comment: @HughMungus, that's not what Scott is saying - he's telling you that you're printing the entire list instead of slicing off just one value from the list.